# Spark UI event timeline 'empty' space

Tags: apache-spark

When I examine a specific event timeline for a specific stage in the browser-based UI I notice consistently that the Executor Computing Time displayed in the graphic never exceeds a certain length. In the attached image you can see that several tasks take different amounts of time, but the longer ones have the same 'length' of green bar, representing the Executor Computing Time. The remainder of the task length is taken up by 'empty' blue bar which does not indicate anything is happening. The values given for Executor Compile Time in the tables below are much longer, and would seem that they need to take up the entire empty part of the bar.

Note that this blue part of the bar is not Getting Result Time, it's just 'empty'. This is verified in the tabulated timing values.

Even when I change the time scale these green bars stay the same length so I am guessing this is a bug in the way Executor Compile Time is displayed in the UI.

Is this a known issue, or is there another explanation?

I'm using Chrome on Windows, running Spark 2.0 on a remote server.

[IMAGE: Task running time and 'empty' space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTSxV.png)

Comment: Note that hovering gives you the time for each category. The length of the box seems to correspond to the sum of the values obtained by hovering (if the axis is in ms as I guessed). Interesting. Notice also that by enabling zooming, this bar stay fixed while the axis changes. I guess it's a bug.

Comment: there are a bunch of issues related to the event timeline. Not certain if it maps to this observation. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8778?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK%20AND%20text%20~%20%22event%20timeline%22